# Help Understanding Bessel's Correction Derivation

Tags: self-study, variance

I am trying to understand the derivation for the unbiased estimate of the population variance from a random sample.  The intuition makes sense to me (if I'm understanding correctly).  Unless $\bar{x}-\mu=0$ your difference measure is going to be off by $\bar{x}-\mu$.  So to estimate the expected discrepancy we just need to find $E[(\bar{x}-\mu)^2]$.  Then $\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}E[s^2_{\rm biased}]=\sigma^2-\Var(\bar{x})$ and we can rearrange to find an unbiased estimate.

I am stuck at this point:

$$\Var(\bar{x})=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

I understand the following:
\begin{align}
\Var(\bar{x}) &= \Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)  \\
\Var(\bar{x}) &= \frac{1}{n^2}\Var(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)  \\
\Var(\bar{x}) &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Var(x_i) 
\end{align}
What I don't follow is how $\Var(x_i)=\sigma^2$.  If we have a bunch of independent samples $n$ isn't their variance $s^2$ and we're back to the beginning?

Comment: s^2 is the sample variance and sigma squared is the population variance. The steps you have taken are correct. Var(x_i) is sigma squared!

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I am still stuck on why Var(x_i) is sigma squared.  If we take random samples x_i from the population, then don't they follow a distribution with a sample variance not population variance which is what we're trying to correct for in the first place?

Comment: I have trouble understanding the sentence that says E[s^2_biased]=sigma squared -Var(x_bar)..  Also I think x_bar =mu has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The distinction is between the random variables and their observed values. This can get confusing in the notation.  Let's take the concrete example of N(mu, sigma squared)  s^2/(n-1) is an unbiased estimate of sigma squared s^2/n is the maximum likelihood estimate of sigma squared and is biased by a factor of n/(n-1).

Comment: @Michael MathJax markup works in comments as well as in posts.  Surround your $\TeX$ with dollar signs.  For instance, "\$s^2/(n-1)\$" will be rendered as "$s^2/(n-1)$".

Comment: @Daniel It all comes down to something you haven't explained: exactly how is $\sigma^2$ defined?  I will bet it is the very name given to $\operatorname{Var}(x_i)$ in the first place.

Comment: Ahhhh, right.  I think I was confusing a given random sample with the expected variance of the variable itself which is of course by definition $\sigma^2$